# Diagnose a multiple definition error

Tags: c++, linkage, icc

I have a library, QPhiX, that I want to compile with a large application, Chroma. Both libraries have other dependencies, it is quite an entangled thing with around a million lines. QPhiX has compiled cleanly and I have installed it into `~/local-jureca`.

During the compilation of Chroma, the Intel C++ version 17 compiler gives me errors like these:

```
../../lib/libchroma.a(syssolver_mdagm_aggregate.o): In function `QPhiX::CommsUtils::sumDouble(double*)': 
syssolver_mdagm_aggregate.cc:(.text+0x180): multiple definition of `QPhiX::CommsUtils::sumDouble(double*)' 
../../lib/libchroma.a(syssolver_linop_aggregate.o):syssolver_linop_aggregate.cc:(.text+0x1d0): first defined here
```

The compiler call is this, I have broken down the long line by hand. Some flags are replicated because the `configure` picks up the flags of the used libraries and mangles them into the `CXXFLAGS`.

```
/usr/local/software/jureca/Stages/2016b/software/impi/2017.0.098-iccifort-2017.0.098-GCC-5.4.0/bin64/mpiicpc \
    -I/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/Sources/chroma/mainprogs/main \
    -I/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/Sources/chroma/lib \
    -I../../lib \
    -O2 \
    -Wall \
    -fopenmp \
    --std=c++11 \
    -I/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/local-jureca/include \
    -I/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/local-jureca/include/libxml2 \
    -I/usr/local/software/jureca/Stages/2016b/software/GMP/6.1.1-iccifort-2017.0.098-GCC-5.4.0/include \
    -O2 \
    -Wall \
    -fopenmp \
    -I/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/local-jureca/include \
    -O2 \
    -Wall \
    -fopenmp \
    -L../../lib \
    -L/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/local-jureca/lib \
    -L/usr/local/software/jureca/Stages/2016b/software/GMP/6.1.1-iccifort-2017.0.098-GCC-5.4.0/lib \
    -L/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/local-jureca/lib \
    -L../../other_libs/qdp-lapack/lib
    -o cfgtransf \
    cfgtransf.o \
    -lchroma \
    -lqdp \
    -lXPathReader \
    -lxmlWriter \
    -lqio \
    -llime \
    -L/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/local-jureca/lib \
    -lxml2 \
    -lm \
    -lqmp \
    -lqmp \
    -lintrin \
    -lfiledb \
    -lfilehash \
    -lgmp \
    -lqphix_solver \
    -lqdp-lapack
```

I have looked where the function `QPhiX::CommsUtils::sumDouble(double*)` gets defined. Within Chroma, there is not a single use of this function. Therefore the error is within QPhiX but one did not notice since no file there includes the header file `qphix/include/qphix/comm.h`. Stripped down, this file is here:

```
namespace QPhiX {
#ifndef QPHIX_DO_COMMS
    namespace CommsUtils {
        void sumDouble(double *d) {}
    }

#else

// I see a multiple definition error of `sumDouble` when compiling Chroma. I
// suspect that somehow both flags are passed. Therefore check that only one of
// the mutually exclusive flags is given. Perhaps it would be even better to
// use a `#else` here.
#if defined(QPHIX_FAKE_COMMS) && defined(QPHIX_QMP_COMMS)
#error                                                                         \
    "You must specify QPHIX_FAKE_COMMS xor QPHIX_QMP_COMMS when specifying QPHIX_DO_COMMS."
#endif

#ifdef QPHIX_FAKE_COMMS
    namespace CommsUtils {
        void sumDouble(double *d) {}
    };
#endif // QPHIX_FAKE_COMMS

#ifdef QPHIX_QMP_COMMS
    namespace CommsUtils {
        void sumDouble(double *d) { QMP_sum_double(d); };
    };
#endif // QPHIX_QMP_COMMS

#endif // ifndef QPHIX_DO_COMMS
}; // Namespace
```

The preprocessor branches look such that only one definition can be activated in this file. In the case that both `QPHIX_FAKE_COMMS` and `QPHIX_QMP_COMMS` were given by the build system, the `#error` should have been activated.

Both error messages are caused in `libchroma.a`, that must be an intermediate building step in compiling Chroma. The two definitions are in different object files (`syssolver_mdagm_aggregate.o` and `syssolver_linop_aggregate.o`), but neither matching C++ source file contains the function definition, they both just include the QPhiX header file. There the function `sumDouble` is defined.

What happens here? Do the two definitions of `sumDouble` become a problem even if it is the same of the three variants in both cases? Or does this mean that two Chroma source files include the `qphix/include/qphix/comm.h` with different preprocessor flags set?

How can I fix this? Just making all the offending functions in QPhiX explicitly `inline`? They seem to only delegate to the QDP++ library anyway, so inlining just be just fine.

Perhaps I got unlucky and the `devel` branches of QPhiX and Chroma do not work together, but `master` does not work either. So I again wonder what I am doing wrong, assuming that people developing this software can compile it just fine.

Comment: you need to put `inline` if you define function in header file

Comment: That's what I thought. Or the definition must be into a source file that would then go into `libqphix.a` *once* while compiling `comm.cc`. Do you have an idea why there is code this library that does not compile? I mean, somebody else should have noticed, right‽

Comment: I have no idea, maybe because no one have ever use it or it is meant to be an internal header? Why not suggest a fix to it? BTW are you refers to [this](https://github.com/JeffersonLab/qphix)?

Comment: It now works! Thank you very much! Do you want to convert your comment into an answer? I'll accept it then. Otherwise I guess my question could be deleted since it is somewhat narrow in scope and a fairly simple answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define function in header file, you need to put inline before it.

---

Otherwise if more than one file include it, when the linker try to link, it will find multiple definition exist and report a multiple definition error (if there is inline, the linker will pick one of them).

Comment: BTW, instead of `inline`, you can put `static` before it or use `anonymous namespace` to resolve the multiple definition error, but this will make many copy of the function/variable.